# Remove a linebreak in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following lines of text:

```
W&BL 15&384&320&214&1&S235JR&&&&&&&&&&S&&0.267&&&&4&&
N&214.nc
A&214&1&&15
W&BL 15&384&320&215&1&S235JR&&&&&&&&&&S&&0.267&&&&4&&
N&215.nc
A&213&2&&14
```

I want to remove the linebreaks so the outcome will be like this:

```
A&213&2&&14W&BL 15&384&320&214&1&S235JR&&&&&&&&&&S&&0.267&&&&4&&N&214.nc
A&214&1&&15W&BL 15&384&320&215&1&S235JR&&&&&&&&&&S&&0.267&&&&4&&N&215.nc
```

I do this because I need to format these lines and I'm putting the whole textfile in a reader per line. When I filter this with linebreaks I can't properly search through the lines. Since I need to delete everything after the `S235JR`, replace the `&` with `;` and start the line with the `BL` code.

If someone knows a smarter/better solution to filter these lines, you will be my hero of the day.

Edit for clarification:

This is a example and how it needs to be formatted:

```
H&HEA100&1712&&1001&2&S235JR&&&HEA100 -  1712&&&&&&&S&&0.96&&&&2&&&1.7&0.2&0.2
N&1001.nc
W&BL 15&384&320&215&1&S235JR&&&&&&&&&&S&&0.267&&&&4&&
N&215.ncA&214&1&&15
H&L80X8&375&&1010&1&S275JR&&&L80X8 -  375&&&&&&&S&&0.117&&&&4&&&0.4&0.1&0.1
N&1010.nc
```

After formatting:

```
H;HEA100;1712;;1001;2;S235JR;
BL 15;384;320;215;1;S235JR;
L80X8;375;;1010;1;S275JR;
```

The input is a text file imported with a StreamReader. The `H`, `BL 15` and `L80X8` are determined after 6 `&` characters. The program was originally written in DOS and I need to convert it into C#. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how I could get this to work. I tried this:  `string linefixed = Regex.Replace(line, @"^\s*$", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline).TrimEnd();

                    MessageBox.Show(linefixed);` The messagebox is for testing purposes.

Comment: Combining lines until it hits `N&21x.nc`.

Comment: What is the input for your program? If it is some kind of `Stream` you could read it line by line. When a line does not end with N&21x.nc append it to the previous line. If a line does end with N&21x.nc append it as well, write is to the output stream.

Comment: I can't seem to follow your example... The first line of the result is clear, but why does the second line start where it does? Where did the `A&214&1&&15` and the `W&` from the source go?

Comment: Something went wrong with the editing.

@venerik How do I append lines from the streamreader to the string?

Comment: Your clarification is more confusing than the first draft of this question. Now it seems that you want to start a newline whenever you have a BL in your input text, catch the content until the S235JR; and discard everything until the next BL. Could you give an example with 3 output lines?

Answer (score 3):

```
x.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);
```

where x is string.

Comment: Note that this doesn't change the value in `x`, you have to assign the result of the expression to something.

Comment: Note that this will remove EVERY linebreaks (or newline?), also the ones required after the .nc

Answer (score 1):

From the example in your question, it looks like you want to remove line breaks, *but* keep every third line break.

You can use a regular expression that matches three lines, and remove the two line breaks between them:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)", "$1$2$3");
```

Comment: The beginning of a line starts with _a letter_`&` and the end has `N&215.nc`. For example: `W&BL 15&384&320&215&1&S235JR&&&&&&&&&&S&&0.267&&&&4&&
N&215.nc`. From that line I need to delete everything after the `S235JR` and replace each `&` character with a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = x.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

x is your string Object;

Comment: Note that this doesn't change the value in `x`, you have to assign the result of the expression to something.

Comment: `'\r\n'` is not C#, is it? `'` denotes a char and `\r\n` are two chars.

Comment: Thanks Thomas & Guffa.  I've corrected their oversight

Answer (score 0):

```
string x = x.Replace("&", ";");
string x1 = x.Substring(x.IndexOf("H;"), x.IndexOf("S235JR;", x.IndexOf("H;")) - x.IndexOf("H;")+7);
string x2 = x.Substring(x.IndexOf("BL 15;"), x.IndexOf("S235JR;", x.IndexOf("BL 15;")) - x.IndexOf("BL 15;")+7);
string x3 = x.Substring(x.IndexOf("L80X8;"), x.IndexOf("S275JR;", x.IndexOf("L80X8;")) - x.IndexOf("L80X8;")+7);
string result = x1 + "\r\n" + x2 + "\r\n" + x3;
```